# What does satisfactory completion of Master's degree mean?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I received a conditional offer with following condition from a university in London, UK with following condition.

> Subject to satisfactory completion of Master's to be confirmed by an official original document from your current university's registration department.

What does satisfactory completion of Master's mean? I haven't found a clear definition of "satisfactory" degree. Is there a chance that they use this term as an accuse to decline my offer? No matter what degree I will achieve, they can classify as "unsatisfactory" and reject me.

Comment: Simply that the document (say a transcript) shows that you were awarded the degree.

Comment: @GEdgar there will be no restriction whether distinction or merit is awarded?

Comment: @quallenjäger At least in the US, it's fairly typical to talk about satisfactorily completing something, e.g. a degree program, which clarifies that unsatisfactory completion modes, such as failing out, aren't acceptable.

Comment: @GEdgar - Please write an answer.

Comment: @Nat - Or your comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Satisfactory completion means that you've completed the program by satisfying the requirements, as opposed to, say, simply leaving.  Additionally it implies meeting any final evaluation criteria, e.g. passing any final exams.

Usually this phrase doesn't imply anything more by itself, though it's not uncommon for additional constraints to be attached to it.  For example, if they want your GPA to be above a certain point, they may say "satisfactory completion with a GPA of at least 3.5".